# React Native, unable to resolve module `DataPickerIOS`

Tags: react-native

I tried the command line suggested in the screenshot, but still no success, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: lol, code pls..

Answer (score 0):

restart you packager server and use --reset-cache at the end.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

If this doesn't work then maybe the module is missing so first install the module. Use

```
npm --save <module name>
```

and then run the command to restart the server ( mentioned above)